# Query database in Application_BeginRequest (Global.asax)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to query a database from the Application_BeginRequest in my Global.asax file to get my currently 301 from a database instead of pure code.

But i can't seem to find how to do this, i cant write SqlConnection or similar like i'm used to when i'm about to start a SQL query.

Is it even possible to get this type of code:

```
if (Request.Url.ToString() == "http://www.mywebsite.com")
    {
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://www.mywebsite.org");
    }
```

to be generated from the database? And if so, how can i do it? I've tried to search but i can't seem to find any solution for my problem. An answer would be highly appreciated!

/Lucas

Comment: FYI: you can use Response.RedirectPermanent("http://www.mywebsite.org");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written the right code , you can proceed and implement SQLCommand to fetch data from database

e.g.

```
//Write SQLCommand to get the data in url variable, suppose you have GetDataFromDatabase method written in your helper static class or somewhere else in the page gives stored url from database

string url = GetDataFromDatabase();

if (Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Equals(url.ToLower()))
{
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.AddHeader("Location", url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, yes. You could do the following:

- Select a row from you table where the url is equals to
  `Request.Url.ToString()`.
- If a row is returned you know that you need to redirect.
- Take the new url from the row and use that in the
  `Response.AddHeader` call